# new Function() with variable parameters

Tags: javascript

I need to create a function with variable number of parameters using `new Function()` constructor. Something like this:

```
args = ['a', 'b'];
body = 'return(a + b);';

myFunc = new Function(args, body);
```

Is it possible to do it without `eval()`?

---

Thank you very much, guys! Actually, a+b was not my primary concern. I'm working on a code which would process and expand templates and I needed to pass unknown (and variable) number of arguments into the function so that they would be introduced as local variables.

For example, if a template contains:

```
<span> =a </span>
```

I need to output the value of parameter `a`. That is, if user declared expanding function as

```
var expand = tplCompile('template', a, b, c)
```

and then calls

```
expand(4, 2, 1)
```

I need to substitute `=a` with `4`. And yes, I'm well aware than Function is similar to `eval()` and runs very slow but I don't have any other choice.

Comment: Why not just loop through the array?  There's probably a better way to go about whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: I fear eval can't be avoided as you try to evaluate pure text as code.

Comment: There are better ways to do this. If you absolutely must use `new Function()`, that sounds like a homework assignment. In that case, the instructor is teaching you how do to things the wrong way.

Answer (score 59):

You can do this using [*apply()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
args = ['a', 'b', 'return(a + b);'];
myFunc = Function.apply(null, args);
```

Without the `new` operator, `Function` gives exactly the same result.  You can use array functions like [*push*()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), [*unshift()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) or [*splice()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to modify the array before passing it to apply.

You can also just pass a comma-separated string of arguments to *Function*:

```
args = 'a, b';
body = 'return(a + b);';

myFunc = new Function(args, body);
```

On a side note, are you aware of the [*arguments*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/functions_and_function_scope/arguments) object?  It allows you to get all the arguments passed into a function using array-style bracket notation:

```
myFunc = function () {
    var total = 0;

    for (var i=0; i < arguments.length; i++)
        total += arguments[i];

    return total;
}

myFunc(a, b);
```

This would be more efficient than using the *Function* constructor, and is probably a much more appropriate method of achieving what you need.

Comment: You suggestion's just perfect! The following works like a charm:

args = 'a, b';
body = 'return(a + b);';

myFunc = new Function(args, body);

Comment: @mtelis: great stuff, I'm glad it helped you :-) You can mark an answer as accepted by clicking the check mark just below the voting arrows.  And welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Won't the `this` variable be different in `myFunc` if you don't use new operator?

Comment: @Timo: In this case, no. Like most built-in constructors, omitting the `new` operator makes no behavioural difference.  We're not using the `this` object here anyway.

Comment: @AndyE thanks for the quick reply, I didn't realize that `new Function` was the actual function and not some placeholder name... whoops

Answer (score 8):

@AndyE's answer is correct **if** the constructor doesn't care whether you use the `new` keyword or not. Some functions are not as forgiving.

If you find yourself in a scenario where you *need* to use the `new` keyword and you need to send a variable number of arguments to the function, you can use this

```
function Foo() {
  this.numbers = [].slice.apply(arguments);
};


var args = [1,2,3,4,5]; // however many you want
var f = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
Foo.apply(f, args);

f.numbers;          // [1,2,3,4,5]
f instanceof Foo;   // true
f.constructor.name; // "Foo"
```

---

**ES6 and beyond!**

```js
// yup, that easy
function Foo (...numbers) {
  this.numbers = numbers
}

// use Reflect.construct to call Foo constructor
const f =
  Reflect.construct (Foo, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

// everything else works
console.log (f.numbers)          // [1,2,3,4,5]
console.log (f instanceof Foo)   // true
console.log (f.constructor.name) // "Foo"
```

Comment: This answer deals with arbitrary constructors. However, the question was specifically about the `Function` constructor. The function constructor does not have to be used with `new` at all and so it’s sufficient to just use `Function.apply(null, args)`.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this:

```js
let args = '...args'
let body = 'let [a, b] = args;return a + b'

myFunc = new Function(args, body);
console.log(myFunc(1, 2)) //3
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want an annoymous function to call an arbitary function.

```js
// user string function
var userFunction = 'function x(...args) { return args.length}';
```

## Wrap it

```js
var annoyFn = Function('return function x(...args) { return args.length}')()
// now call it
annoyFn(args)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just wanting a `sum(...)` function:

```
function sum(list) {
    var total = 0, nums;
    if (arguments.length === 1 && list instanceof Array) {
        nums = list;
    } else {
        nums = arguments;
    }
    for (var i=0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        total += nums[i];
    }
    return total;
}
```

Then,

```
sum() === 0;
sum(1) === 1;
sum([1, 2]) === 3;
sum(1, 2, 3) === 6;
sum([-17, 93, 2, -841]) === -763;
```

If you want more, could you please provide more detail? It's rather difficult to say how you can do something if you don't know what you're trying to do.

Comment: You should add `var nums;`; otherwise you make nums global which is certainly not desired.

Comment: True. That was careless. Thanks for picking that up.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few different ways you could write that.

```
// assign normally
var ab = ['a','b'].join('');
alert(ab);
// assign with anonymous self-evaluating function
var cd = (function(c) {return c.join("");})(['c','d']);
alert(cd);
// assign with function declaration
function efFunc(c){return c.join("");}
var efArray = ['e','f'];
var ef = efFunc(efArray);
alert(ef);
// assign with function by name
var doFunc = function(a,b) {return window[b](a);}
var ghArray = ['g','h'];
var ghFunc = function(c){return c.join("");}
var gh = doFunc(ghArray,'ghFunc');
alert(gh);
// assign with Class and lookup table
var Function_ = function(a,b) {
  this.val = '';
  this.body = b.substr(0,b.indexOf('('));
  this.args = b.substr(b.indexOf('(')+1,b.lastIndexOf(')')-b.indexOf('(')-1);
  switch (this.body) {
    case "return": 
      switch (this.args) {
        case "a + b": this.val = a.join(''); break;
      }
    break;
  }
} 
var args = ['i', 'j'];
var body = 'return(a + b);';
var ij = new Function_(args, body);
alert(ij.val);
```

Comment: But that's just equivalent to `var ab = (function(c) {...})(['a','b'])`!

Comment: @Chris Morgan, true true.  I was thinking he wanted to map the functions to variables rather than put them into one function expression and evaluate it.

Comment: Thank you very much, guys! Actually, a+b was not my primary concern. I'm working on a code which would process and expand templates and I needed to pass unknown (and variable) number of arguments into the function so that they would be introduced as local variables. For example, if a template contains:

Comment: <span> =a </span> I need to output the value of parameter "a". That is, if user declared expanding function as var expand = tplCompile('template', a, b, c) t

Answer (score 0):

A new feature introduced in ES5 is the `reduce` method of arrays. [You can use it to sum numbers, and it is possible to use the feature in older browsers with some compatibility code.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Answer (score -1):

```
new Function(...)
```

> Declaring function in this way causes
>   the function not to be compiled, and
>   is potentially slower than the other
>   ways of declaring functions.

Let is examine it with [JSLitmus](http://www.broofa.com/Tools/JSLitmus/)  and run a small test script:

```
<script src="JSLitmus.js"></script>
<script>

JSLitmus.test("new Function ... ", function() { 
    return new Function("for(var i=0; i<100; i++) {}"); 
});

JSLitmus.test("function() ...", function() { 
       return (function() { for(var i=0; i<100; i++) {}  });
});

</script>
```

What I did above is create a `function expression` and `function constructor` performing same operation. The result is as follows:

**FireFox Performance Result**

[image: FireFox Performance Result]

**IE Performance Result**

[image: IE Performance Result]

Based on facts I recommend to use `function expression` instead of `function constructor`

```
var a = function() {
 var result = 0;
 for(var index=0; index < arguments.length; index++) {
  result += arguments[index];
 }
 return result;
 }
alert(a(1,3));
```

Comment: Could you link the resource where you took that sentence about performance from?

Comment: the citation is *wrong*, there are alot of myths about this. The function *is compiled* just after the moment you call the [`Function` constructor](http://sideshowbarker.github.com/es5-spec/#x15.3.2.1). After that it is just like *any other user-defined function*, no performance penalties, the *slow part* may be the function creation, but not the function itself after its creation...

Comment: of course, the *function creation* is slower, the engine will need to re-parse and evaluate the `FormalParameterList` and `FunctionBody` at runtime, and occurs *thousands of times* within your test. What I'm trying to tell you is that the function, *once it is created* by the `Function` constructor is "compiled" and it will have a performance equivalent to a function created by other means. Modify your test to check *invocation*, *not creation*, and you will see really similar results between the two. See [this test](http://j.mp/crC9xY) and this [question](http://j.mp/ddZu3G) Cheers :)

Answer (score -1):

```
function construct(){
         this.subFunction=function(a,b){
         ...  
         }
}
var globalVar=new construct();
```

vs.

```
var globalVar=new function (){
              this.subFunction=function(a,b){
              ...
              }
}
```

I prefer the second version if there are sub functions.

Answer (score -1):

the b.apply(null, arguments) does not work properly when b inherits a prototype, because 'new' being omitted, the base constructor is not invoked.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a comment on another answer? It doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question.

Comment: This question asks specifically for the case `b === Function`, where `apply` does indeed work (it doesn't need to be called as a constructor). For the general case, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1606797/1048572).

Comment: it is indeed a comment to @Andy E, but SO won't let me comment directly

Comment: Maybe I did not understand the question accurately, it just so happens that I was looking for a solution to a similar problem: pass arguments through a call chain, up to a constructor.

Answer (score -1):

In this sample i used [lodash](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.4/lodash.min.js):

```
function _evalExp(exp, scope) {
  const k = [null].concat(_.keys(scope));
  k.push('return '+exp);
  const args = _.map(_.keys(scope), function(a) {return scope[a];});
  const func = new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(Function, k));
  return func.apply(func, args);
}

_evalExp('a+b+c', {a:10, b:20, c:30});
```