# Javascript callback from form attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, callback

I have setup some automatic form submission code. Basically when a form is submitted javascript takes care of it, finding all inputs and such, and sending the data via ajax to the action attr of the form.

```
$j('body').delegate('form', 'submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($j(this).prop('data-callback', true))
        asf.forms.processForm($j(this).attr('name'), $j(this).attr('data-callback'));
    else
        asf.forms.processForm($j(this).attr('name'));
});
```

But i need to include callbacks. I need to make the code global so i cant code any specifics for each form. So i thought of adding an attribute with the callback function name like so:

```
<form action="" method="" data-callback="posts.addPost()">
```

The problem is I dont know how to fire that function inside javascript. Any ideas?
I cant use onsubmit because i need access to all of the forms information which means doing this callback within the ajax response.

Thanks

Comment: If I understand you correctly you could use eval($j(this).attr("data-callback")) Is that what you needed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165707/passing-a-javascript-function-through-inline-data-attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this without resorting to `eval`, I suggest you store all your "form callbacks" in an object, like so:

```
var formCallbacks = {
  'posts.addPost': function() {
    // ...
  },
  // ...
};
```

Using your `data-callback` mechanism, you would look up the callback in the response handler:

```
function(args, callbackName) {
  formCallbacks[callbackName]();
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I know that eval is evil, but it seems only reasonable solution:

```
eval($(form).attr('data-callback'));
```

If you put only method name in `data-callback` attribute (eg. `data-callback="posts.addPost"`) it's possible to call it without eval:

```
var methodName = $(form).attr('data-callback');
var parts = methodName.split('.');
var method = window;

$(parts).each(function(){
    method = method[this];
});

method();
```

Comment: not only solution :) i've made it that way:
function run(code) {
 var res = new Function('return ' + code + '|| false');
 return res(); 
}
run($(form).attr('data-callback'));

Comment: This is almost the same. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183591/new-function-with-variable-parameters) for example