# Passing a Javascript function through inline data- attributes

Tags: javascript, html, function, attributes, callback

I'm working with a Javascript file upload library, and one of it's features is that it uses HTML5 inline data- attributes to pass information to the plugin.

This is working great for anything data related, strings, numbers etc., however the plugin has some callback methods you can assign function to. My problem is that when trying to pass a javascript function through these inline data attributes, like this:

```
<input type="file" name="test" data-on-finish="alert();">
```

The plugin picks up the reference to the onFinish() callback method fine, but when it tries to execute whatever javascript I put in there I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object alert(); has no method 'call'
```

I'm assuming it's reading the `alert();` as a string. Any idea how I can pass through executable javascript to the plugin?

I believe the plugin I'm using is an extension to the jQuery file upload plugin:
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options

**Update:**
I've also tried using globally defined functions, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myTesting(){
       alert('yay');
    }
</script>
<input type="file" name="test" data-on-finish="myTesting">
```

I've tried changing the `data-on-finish` attribute to `myTesting`, `myTesting()`, still had no luck...

Comment: Gave it a try, no luck. I've added the update above.

Comment: I think the eval() will do the job but can be dangerous :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

Answer (score 20, accepted):

why not place the name of the callback instead? something like

```
//for example, a global function
window['someFunctionName'].call();

//a namespaced function
//similar to doing ns.someFunctionName()
ns['someFunctionName'].call();
```

Comment: I tried this to no avail unfortunately. It is still trying to call the `call()` method on a string it seems

Comment: @petehare no, its not calling a string. the answer uses that string to point to that function in a certain namespace.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is trying to call a function back, as in, myfunction.call(

Try passing is a function like this.

```
<input type="file" name="test" data-on-finish="myFunction;">

function myFunction(){
 alert('I am alerting');
};
```

Comment: Similar thing happening, it's reading `myFunction;` as a string and trying to run the `"myFunction;".call()` method on the string...

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```js
$(function() {
  function test() {
    alert("ok");
  }

  $(".test").data("test", test);
  $(".test").data("test")();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
</div>
```