# Pass a callback function as a html data attribute

Tags: javascript

I have created a DOM structure like this

```
<div data-execute="someFunction.abc" id="someId">
  </div>
```

I am able to retrive the attribute in js but I intend to execute this as a  callback function. So I am doing  like this

```
var x = document.getElementById("someId").getAttribute('data-execute');
```

As expected this is returning someFunction.abc .But on consoling typeof(x) it is showing "string".Please refer to this fiddle

```js
var someFunction = function() {
  alert("Hello")
}
var load = (function(module, global) {
  var x = document.getElementById("someId").getAttribute('data-execute');
  console.log(typeof(x))

}(load || {}, this))
```

```html
<div data-execute="someFunction.abc" id="someId">
  Some Function
</div>
```

I also checked this link 
[Passing a Javascript function through inline data- attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165707/passing-a-javascript-function-through-inline-data-attributes)

But no way I am able to execute it as a call back function.Any help will be truly appreciable.

Comment: What is abc? It's a paremeter?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<div data-execute="someFunction.abc" id="someId"></div>

var x = document.getElementById("someId").getAttribute('data-execute');
window[x].call();
```

Comment: This will work, but without .abc at the end. Not sure should it be parameter, maybe?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) methodon the function defined in the global scope, you can access it in the global window ojbect.

Ref:

> The call() method calls a function with a given this value and
>   arguments provided individually.

I have assumed the code after the point is a paramter to pass to the function.

Code:

```
var someFunction = function (p) {
    alert(p)
}
var load = (function (module, global) {
    var x = document.getElementById("someId").getAttribute('data-execute');
    window[x.split('.')[0]].call(undefined, x.split('.')[1]);

}(load || {}, this))
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/5bjsmu3x/

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same question and I found this solution :

HTML :

```
<element data-call="return alert('callback');">
```

JS :

```
Function(YourElement.getAttribute('data-callback'))();
```

You can store it in a variable and add parameters too :

HTML :

```
<element data-call="return str.toUpperCase();">
```

JS :

```
var fn = Function("str", YourElement.getAttribute('data-callback'));
var returned = fn("Test String");
```