# creating new class instance and applying arguments as array

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use of .apply() with 'new' operator. Is this possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606797/use-of-apply-with-new-operator-is-this-possible)

I need to create a new insance of a class (`new SomeClass()`), but the arguments I need to pass is an array. I know I can call functions with `apply()` and pass the array of arguments as the second argument to `apply`, but how can I do this when creating a new instance?

Comment: @JamesMontagne i can't get that example to work though. I get this error: TypeError: Function.prototype.apply: Arguments list has wrong type

Comment: @LordZardeck: Can you show us the code you're trying.  Are you sure you're passing an array?

Answer (score 0):

```
function ​myClass​()
{
    if(this instanceof arguments.callee)
    {
        init.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    function init()
    {
        this.args=arguments;
        console.log(arguments);
    }
}

var myArray=[1,2,3];
var obj=new myClass(myArray);
console.log(obj.args);
```

[Example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/y494n/) Hope I understood what you need and this one may help you.

Comment: i'm not in control of the constructor.

Comment: You didn't define the class/function ?