# Extending kinetic.js shape with coffescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, kineticjs

I've been messing around with coffeescript and I would like to use Kinetic.js to perform some graphical operations.

I really like coffeescripts classes so I wanted to use them to create custom sprites.

Below is my attempt of extending Kinetic.Circle:

```
class Particle extends Kinetic.Circle
    constructor: (x,y,size,color) ->
        Kinetic.Circle.class @, {
            x: x
            y: y
            width: size
            height: size
            fill: color
        }
```

Note that I did not use "super" in the constructor as advised in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530450/coffeescript-class) question.

When calling the constructor the following error is thrown:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a){this.___init(a)} has no method 'class'
```

... in the generated javascript:

```
  Particle = (function(_super) {
    __extends(Particle, _super);

    function Particle(x, y, size, color) {
      Kinetic.Circle["class"](this, {
        x: x,
        y: y,
        width: size,
        height: size,
        fill: color
      });
    }

    return Particle;

  })(Kinetic.Circle);
```

Is it possible to extend Kinetic shapes in coffeescript style without using too much violence?

Comment: `Kinetic.Circle` have no static `.class()` method, where did you get it? Looks like it should be `Kinetic.Circle.call` instead.

Comment: I got it from the linked question, tried your suggestion and it worked! Add it as an answer and I'll accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Kinetic.Circle` have no static `.class()` method and I have no idea where did you get it.

Looks like it should be `Kinetic.Circle.call` instead:

```
class Particle extends Kinetic.Circle
  constructor: (x, y, size, color) ->
    Kinetic.Circle.call @,
      x: x
      y: y
      width: size
      height: size
      fill: color
```

Which is exactly what was suggested in a linked question.

Comment: Hmm, I guessed this turned out to be just stupidity from my part then. Thanks!