# JavaScript setting dynamic/custom class name when calling 'apply()'

Tags: javascript

Following on from [Use of .apply() with 'new' operator. Is this possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606797/use-of-apply-with-new-operator-is-this-possible)
, I'd like to be able to set a custom name to the class when new'ing it using this method. At the moment when I follow this method and `console.log` the returned class it just goes by the name of 'F' or whatever the `prototype`'s name is.

I'd like to be able to change this to something I can set, preferably the name of the class I'd like the `new`; is this possible?

Comment: I don't think there's a wayto do this without `eval()`

Comment: if you want a per-class name : constructor.name is here for you. If you want a per-instance information, add it to all your classes.

Comment: Really it's for debugging purposes. I'm gonna look into how Angular does it.