# JavaScript: Creating an object generically from its type and calling its constructor

Tags: javascript, object, constructor

Say there's a JavaScript object with a childType property, which is an object constructor, and you want to write a generic addChild method. It needs to create an instance of this.childType, and invoke its constructor, passing whatever arguments were passed into addChild.

To be clear, the point is for each collection to create child objects itself, using the inherited generic addChild method and its known childType, not to validate the type of passed-in child objects.

I didn't think this would be hard to do, but I've tried various things and only failed so far.

**UPDATE:**

I've updated the [demo plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/XrsGkwGBXT3vyCpylI6i) with the best solution I know of so far, and included some comments about the issue in the code. The failed attempts discussed below are no longer there. This solution requires all potential chold objects to have a 'new Agnostic constructor', so it's still not ideal. Further thoughts are most welcome.

---

I know this line is wrong, for two reasons:

```
var child = new this.childItemType.call(args);
```

First is that I think some sort of 'this' needs to be passed to the call function, and I don't see what it'd be there.

Second is probably a result of the first, the error reported in the browser:

```
Uncaught TypeError: function call() { [native code] } is not a constructor
```

I think this should be doable, but the syntax for creating that child object from this.childType and passed arguments escapes me so far. Can someone point out the missing brain cell here?

Comment: `var child = new this.childType(args);`?

Comment: var child = new this[this.childItemType](args); ?

Comment: I've updated the plunk with Clint's 'new Agnostic constructor' solution, which as far as I can tell is the most practical, even with its drawbacks. I also added some further clarifying comments. If he posts it here, I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use of .apply() with 'new' operator. Is this possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606797/use-of-apply-with-new-operator-is-this-possible)

Comment: `var child; childItemType.call(child, args)` is also valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the cleanest approach is to make Dog '`new` Agnostic' (see Effective JavaScript Item 33). Notice how the `Dog` constructor will now return a new `Dog` regardless of how you call it.

```
var Dog = function (name)
{
  if(!(this instanceof Dog)){
    return new Dog(name);
  }

  this.name = name;
  return this;
};
```

And used 'apply' instead of call.

```
var child = this.childItemType.apply(null,arguments);
```

While it does seem like a bit of ceremony for all your constructors, it actually is a pretty good idea anyways. I've found myself making most of my objects `new` agnostic.

Comment: I hadn't seen that technique before, it works well here, thanks. I still keep hoping we're all just having a dull moment, and there's some way to do this without the special constructor, but nobody's brought it up here yet, so this stands as the best way I know of. Thanks again, really very helpful, and Effective JavaScript is on the way to me as we speak...

Comment: I'm glad this solution worked for you. I've really enjoyed Effective JS, it is both well written and informative.  I've still got a long way to go in learning JS. Your question helped me try to 'apply' some of my recent studies. (Good grief... punning... time for bed).

Answer (score 1):

And `new` and `arguments` agnostic oneliner would look like this :)

```
var Dog = function( name ) {
    if ( !(this instanceof Dog) ) { return new (Dog.bind.apply( Dog, [null].concat( Array.prototype.slice.apply( arguments ) ) )); }

    this.name = name;

    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Object.create();` http://plnkr.co/edit/KjqQfev1k42bH0jAUrrA?p=preview

```
var child = Object.create(this.childItemType,props);
```

This changes your structure but it save you from having to write resilient constructor methods.  Also note that you pass in the prototype as the `childItemType`

```
Collection.call(this, Dog.prototype);
```

And instead of passing in arguments to the child object's constructor you pass in a properties object:

```
smiths.addChild({name:{value:'Rover'}});
```

The property object is the trade off here. More about Object.create and the 'second argument' http://dailyjs.com/2012/06/04/js101-object-create/

Comment: Not til IE9 I think, and you're right, parts of the syntax are just odd. It's still interesting to me that what I'm trying to do turns out to be somewhat tricky.

Answer (score 0):

> var child = new this.childItemType.call(args);

No, this indeed tries to use `Function.prototype.call` as a constructor (as the exception message tells you). However, there is no reason to use `call` at all:

```
var child = new this.childItemType(arg, arg2, …);
```

> First is that I think some sort of 'this' needs to be passed to the call function, and I don't see what it'd be there.

Yes, [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) expects something to be used as the `thisArg` for the function. Yet, you seem to want [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) as you have an [argumens array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) `args`.

So on what does the constructor get applied on? It's the new instance - just as like the [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) does it. So to mimick it, we would use

```
var child = Object.create(this.childItemType.prototype);
this.childItemType.apply(child, args);
```

For solutions that work without `Object.create` and also check the return type of the constructor, see [Use of .apply() with 'new' operator. Is this possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606797/use-of-apply-with-new-operator-is-this-possible).

Comment: I'm not so fond of the Object.create syntax or its incompatibilities, but the more succinctly asked prior question you point to has some very valuable solutions, better in some senses than the one I just accepted before I saw this. Really both are valid approches. Thanks very much.

Answer (score -1):

Correct answer is

```
var child = new this.childItemType(args);
```

When you want to create an object of a class/function in javascript then you can directly do `new ClassName(arguments)`, call and apply are normally used to call any method of a class/function with a different scope

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like the dog's name is ['Rover'], not 'Rover'. Added a few other ideas that don't work to the plunk.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm actually downvoting this, because it doesn't work, and anyone coming here later should know that in no uncertain terms.