# Why is my arguments array only having a size of 1?

Tags: javascript

Why am I getting a size of 1 returned by `my_game.size()`? I thought the arguments from `make_game` would get inserted into `game` and so `arguments.length` would be 3, but apparently it's not. What is the reason for this?

```
function game()
{
    var args = arguments;
    this.size = function() { return args.length; };
}

function make_game()
{
    return new game(arguments);
}

var my_game = make_game(4, 'a', true);

console.log(my_game.size()); // 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are passing the entire `arguments` object *as a single argument*

If you want to pass each argument within it as a separate argument then you must do so explicitly:

```
return new game(arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2]);
```

---

If you weren't using a constructor function, then you could use the [apply method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FFunction%2Fapply).

```
return game.apply(this, arguments);
```

… but since you are you would get this result:

```
Uncaught TypeError: function apply() { [native code] } is not a constructor
```

… as it tries to use `apply` as the constructor instead of `game`.

Answer (score 4):

When you do `game(arguments)` inside of `make_game()` you are calling `game()` with a single argument, which is the array of arguments that were passed to `make_game()`.

If you want to pass each argument separately you would normally use [`game.apply(arguments)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), but to get this to work properly with `new` as well it gets a little more complicated:

```
function make_game()
{
    return new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(game, arguments));
}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8843181/505154) has a detailed explanation of how this method works.

Comment: Whoa, that's pretty interesting right there, and far simpler than my solution.  It works because `bind` returns a function all setup for just the right call.  Very slick.

Answer (score 3):

```
return new game(arguments);
```

You are passing in the arguments object, just one object.  So that's one argument.

To forward arguments to a normal function, you would use apply:

```
var fn = function() {
  otherFn.apply(null, arguments);
};
```

But this does 2 things, it passes in the arguments array to use as arguments, but it also sets the execution context (value of `this`).  But a constructor function creates it's own value of this.  This presents a problem...

---

Forwarding the arguments to a constructor is much trickier in plain JS.  In Coffee script, it's easy, but it compiles into some crazy JS.  [See here](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aclass%20Foo%0A%20%20constructor%3A%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20console.log%20arguments.length%0A%0AmakeFoo%20%3D%20-%3E%0A%20%20new%20Foo%28arguments...%29%0A%0AmakeFoo%281%2C2%2C3%29)

The trick seems to be to make an a new subclass with a no-op constructor, and invoke the constructor manually.

```
var newConstructor = function() {}; // no-op constructor
newConstructor.prototype = Game.prototype; // inherit from Game
var child = new newConstructor(); // instantiate no-op constructor
var result = Game.apply(child, arguments); // invoke real constructor.
```

---

But that's pretty hairy.  Perhaps you should rethink your approach.

Answer (score 1):

You pass only one argument to your constructor, and it's `arguments`.

Change

```
var args = arguments;
```

to

```
var args = arguments[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because you are passing only one argument.

```
function game()
{
    var args = arguments;
    this.size = function() { return args.length; };
}

function make_game()
{
    return new game(arguments); // passing only one
}

function make_game2()
{
    return new game(arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2]); // passing three 
}

var my_game = make_game(4, 'a', true);

console.log(my_game.size()); // 1


var my_game2 = make_game2(4, 'a', true);

console.log(my_game2.size()); // 3
```

you can use another function to initialize the object

```
function game()
{
    var args;
    this.size = function() { return args.length; };
    this.init = function(){
        args = arguments;
    }
}

function make_game()
{
    var gm =  new game(); 
    gm.init.apply(gm, arguments);
    return gm;
}


var my_game = make_game(4, 'a', true);

console.log(my_game.size()); // 3
```

This is to demonstrate how it works. It is highly recommended to follow prototype based design.