# Create instance without `new` operator with variable argument list

Tags: javascript, constructor, arguments, instance

I want to create an instance of a `Point` with and without the `new` operator like:

```
Point(5, 10); // returns { x: 5, y: 10 }
// or
new Point(5, 10); // also returns { x: 5, y: 10 }
```

I got it working so far [with the help of StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8843181/612202).

```
function Point() {
  if (!(this instanceof Point)) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    // bring in the context, needed for apply
    args.unshift(null);
    return new (Point.bind.apply(Point, args));
  }
  // determine X and Y values
  var pos = XY(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
  this.x = pos.x;
  this.y = pos.y;
}
```

But that looks horrible, I am even unshifting `null` into the array so I can use `apply`. That just doesn't feel right.

I found a lot of solutions how to achieve it with new constructors and constructor wrappers but I want to keep it as simple as possible (it's just a plain, simple Point).

Is there an easier way to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: Will this have to be for all functions or just 1?  If just 1, quite frankly it'd be better to rewrite that function.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy It's just the `Point` function which I want to behave like this. But of course it's called multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind using ECMAScript 5 functions, `Object.create()` could help:

```
function Point()
{   var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    if (this instanceof Point) return Point.apply(null, args);
    var pos = XY(args); 
    var result = Object.create(Point.prototype);
    result.x = pos.x;
    result.y = pos.y;
    return result;
}
```

If you need ECMAScript 3 compatibility, this crazy, convoluted solution is yet another one (note that it's just a wrapper for an internal equivalent of `new Point`):

```
function Point() 
{   var pos = XY(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
    function internalPoint()
    {   this.x = pos.x;
        this.y = pos.y;
    }
    internalPoint.prototype = Point.prototype;
    return new internalPoint;
}
```

Comment: Ugh! I think I am going with ECMAScript5.

Comment: @DanLee: note that the first method won't be supported by IE8 and below , unless you add a shim for `Object.create()`.  Having said that, I'd agree that the second one is crazy, but less crazy than the one you made :O.

Comment: Haha, yeah it was puzzled together :) I am trying to get my head around these structures.