# Javascript: how to create an instance by class name and an arguments array, like C#?

Tags: javascript

In C# to create an new instance by name and arguments, we can use reflection as follows:

```
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance("Com.Account.Person", 
              new object[] { "Jack", 195, 'USA' });
```

How to do this in Javascript?

```
var clazzName = document.getElementById('clazzName'); // from an input in the page 
var args = document.getElementById('args').split(','); // from another input in the page
var instance = ....... // how?
```

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606797/use-of-apply-with-new-operator-is-this-possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a factory method of the form:

```
function MyFactoryMethod() {
  // Perform instantiation here
  return new MyObject();
}
```

Then you can invoke it, knowing only its name as a string, by doing:

```
var name = "MyFactoryMethod"
var myObj = window[name]();
```

That said, I don't endorse this pattern, and I have an inkling that this will get you into tricky situations down the road.

Comment: Where is the instantiation ?

Comment: Oops, you're right.  Changed this to use a factory pattern.

Comment: @Royi You can't have instantiation because there are no classes. See my answer. This answer will cause confusion to new JavaScript learners.

Comment: Not having classes doesn't mean that the term "instance" is wrong. A class is an object too.

Comment: @elcanrs A class is not the same thing as an object. The term Instance in JavaScript is confusing, although I agree that it is used. Object is much better. A class is a blueprint. An instance is an object built from that blueprint. JavaScript creates only objects. It cannot create blueprints.

Comment: I guess it depends on the language. An "Object" is more abstract than a "Class". In high level scripting languages a class is typically an object, think Ruby, Python, PHP...

Comment: @elclanrs In C# and Java, a class is nothing until it is instantiated into an object. Otherwise, it only exists as a blueprint of an object. JavaScript does not have an equivalent. Everything you do in JavaScript creates objects. Even functions are objects.

Comment: @stepanian: Good to know. I'm not familiar with C# or Java. It seems these terms are confusing in general though. It's like trying to explain functions, scopes and closures in JavaScript...

Answer (score 0):

You can't. JavaScript does not have classes. It has only objects.

Answer (score -1):

If you have for ex.

```
<input id="element" name="elementname" type="text" value="elementvalue" />
```

and want to get "elementname", "text" and "elementvalue"? You can use this:

```
var element = document.getElementById('element');
var name = element.name;
var type = element.type;
var value = element.value;
```