# using [apply] & [new] in javascript to create objects?

Tags: javascript

I've read this [**great question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606797/use-of-apply-with-new-operator-is-this-possible) about using `apply` and `new` in order to create objects on the fly.

The exact question was:

*I want to create an object instance (via the new operator), but pass an arbitrary number of arguments to the constructor. Is this possible*

I have a question regarding the [selected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1608546/859154) answer :

```
/*1*/   function construct(constructor, args) {
/*2*/       function F() {
/*3*/           return constructor.apply(this, args);
/*4*/       }
/*5*/       F.prototype = constructor.prototype;
/*6*/       return new F();
/*7*/   }
```

([working jsbin](http://jsbin.com/modiqoha/2/edit))

All ok.

**But**

I have tried to move line #3 to line #6 : so the final output is :

```
/*1*/   function construct(constructor, args) {
/*2*/      // function F() {
/*3*/      //     return constructor.apply(this, args);
/*4*/      // }
/*5*/       //F.prototype = constructor.prototype;
/*6*/       return new constructor.apply(this, args);
/*7*/   }
```

([**non**-working jsbin](http://jsbin.com/modiqoha/3/edit))

My question is why the second example doesnt work ? what's the difference ?

All I did was to move the code from one place to other place .

example:

```
function calc()
{
   function a() {return 4};

 return a(); // I could easily do `return 4` instead...;
}
```

**Question**:

Why does the moved code , isn't working ?

Comment: I updated my answer p1 so as to include information shared via our chat session yesterday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state that:

```
function construct(constructor, args) {
  function F() {
    return constructor.apply(this, args);
  }
  F.prototype = constructor.prototype;
  return new F();
}
```

should be the same as:

```
function construct(constructor, args) {
  return new constructor.apply(this, args);
}
```

But it actually differs in a few fundamental ways:

**1.** `constructor.apply` is a native non-constructor function. `New` can only create objects from constructors:

> [...] objects may be created [...] via constructors which create objects and then execute code that initialises all or part of them by assigning initial values to their properties. Each constructor is a function that has a property named “prototype” that is used to implement prototype-based inheritance and shared properties. Objects are created by using constructors in new expressions [...]

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.2.1

`F` on the other hand is a [function object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function). All function objects can be used as constructors.

Note: Alon Gubkin said `new constructor.apply(this, args)` doesn't work because `constructor.apply(this, args).prototype` is undefined. This is not true. If it were it would imply that the function call operator's precedence is higher than the new operator (i.e. that 'new constructor.apply(this, args) is the same as new (constructor.apply(this, args))`) [which is not true](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

**2.** Even if `constructor.apply` would be a constructor function it would not be the same as `constructor.prototype`. The prototype of `F` is set to the `constructor's` prototype to make sure all objects that are created through the new operator in combination with `F` are the same as those created in combination with `constructor`. The only difference between `F` and `constructor` being that they are different functions, thus making it possible for `F` to call `constructor` in a more flexible way.

`constructor.apply.prototype` can actually be set to `constructor.prototype`, but `constructor.apply` can still not be used a constructor function.

**3.** In your `new constructor.apply(this, args)` statement the `this` argument is not pointing to the newly created object, but to the `this` in local scope. So even if you could use the `apply` function as a constructor with the `apply's` prototype set to the `constructor's` prototype you would still be passing the wrong `this` to the `constructor` function.

**Note:**
In your example

```
function calc()
{
   function a() {return 4};
   return a(); // I could easily do `return 4` instead...;
}
```

`return` can be used with any kind of expression, while `new` cannot.

Answer (score 0):

You still have to say to it to use the parent prototype.

Also it is a good ideia to specify it to use the extended constructor

Outside the function,

```
construct.prototype = Object.create(constructor.prototype);
construct.prototype.constructor = construct;
```

Edit:

On your second function, you are trying to create a new instance an already instantiated object.

The construct function should be called with new.

http://jsbin.com/modiqoha/7/edit

Comment: You are not defining a new object on the second one.

Comment: hawaii i put so much effort in asking a precise question with code and references. I dont think i deserve this poor explanation. _You are not defining a new object on the second one_ I know it doesnt work . that's why I asked ! what's the difference between those 2 ? it's just moving code

Answer (score 0):

When the code `new foo(...)` is executed, a new object is created, inheriting from `foo.prototype`.

What you have tried to do:

```
return new constructor.apply(this, args);
```

... doesn't work because `constructor.apply(this, args).prototype` is `undefined`.

---

The reason why the original `construct` function still works without:

```
F.prototype = constructor.prototype;
```

is because when you do `return new F();`, F still has a prototype.

Comment: i know this already. I followed the console. but how come the first code does work ?  `return new f()` which is return `new ctor.apply(this,..)` which doesnt work.... tha'ts my problem. it's the same but it's not

Comment: I deleted the comment. I still dont understand the explanation. read my first comment

Comment: Because `F.prototype` is defined. Every function has a prototype. When you do `ctor.apply(this,..)`, it doesn't have a prototype. But when you wrap it with a function, it does.

Comment: `new F()` does not simply replace F with the value returned by F. It firsts checks for `F.prototype`.

Comment: _But when you wrap it with a function, it does_ : so why does this is not working ? http://jsbin.com/kifumaja/2/edit

Comment: function without prototype- also work `function g()
{
}

g.prototype=undefined;

alert ( new g())`