# MDN Function.prototype.bind bound function called as constructor

Tags: javascript, polyfills

I know that when a function returned by `Function.prototype.bind` is called as a constructor, the pre-bound `this` is ignored. This is the behaviour specified in ECMA-262, and the behaviour that [MDN polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) implements. My question is: how that polyfill works in that case? I know that this code is responsoble for that:

```
fNOP = function () {}
```

and

```
return fToBind.apply(this instanceof fNOP && oThis
             ? this
             : oThis,
```

and

```
fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;
fBound.prototype = new fNOP();
```

But why do they need to create this dummy function (`fNOP`), instantiate it and assign to the `fBound`'s prototype and so on. Why can's they just write this:

```
fBound = function foo() {
      return fToBind.apply(this instanceof foo
             ? this
             : oThis,
             aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
    };
```

?

Comment: Because your `foo` function doesn't have the `.prototype` object of the original function.

Answer (score 1):

> But why do they need to create this dummy function (fNOP), instantiate it and assign to the fBound's prototype and so on.

In case your bound function is called with new then `this` will be an instance of FNOP, this because the prototype of the returned function is an instance of FNOP.

`this instanceof fNOP` will be true if I invoke the returned value with `new`. But only because the returned value has an instance of FNOP as it's prototype.

If you would not create a dummy function and do:

```
    fBound = function () {
      return fToBind.apply(this instanceof fBound && oThis
```

Then how would you set fBound's prototype? You could try:

```
   fBound.prototype = new fToBind();
```

But the passed function may throw an exception when called without parameters, you could do:

```
   fBound.prototype = Object.create(fToBind.prototype);
```

But then you need the [polyfil for Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Polyfill) as well and that polyfill basically does the same thing; create a dummy function, set it's prototype and create an instance of the dummy function to have an object with it's prototype set.

Answer (score 1):

Polyfilling `bind` is hard, if not even impossible to do correclty. If you take a look at the [spec](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.4.5), you notice that bound functions are Function objects

- with a [custom [[Call]]](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.4.5.1) internal property
- with a [custom [[Construct]]](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.4.5.2) internal property
- with a [custom [[HasInstance]]](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.4.5.3) internal property
- without a `.prototype` property
- with a specific `.length` property

Clearly, that first quality is the most important, so what we do is to return a function that exhibits this behaviour. You already notice that not everything can be done properly, as `.length` of functions is non-writable, and `prototype` (implicitly created) is non-deleteable.

So how to implement [[Construct]]? We would need to determine whether the function was called with a `new` expression. This cannot be done reliably, as a [`new` call could be faked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1606797) with the help of `.call()`/`.apply()` and `Object.create()`. So what is usually done is testing `Object.getPrototypeOf(this) === constructor.prototype`, or more simple just `this instanceof constructor`. If required, we then would fake the [[Construct]] call of the to-be-bound function with the extended arguments.

So how to implement [[HasInstance]]? The only way to manipulate this is the value of the `.prototype`, which is used for the prototype chain lookups. To make `fBound.[[HasInstance]]` work the same way as `fToBind.[[HasInstance]]`, we need to set `fBound.prototype = fToBind.prototype`.

However, if we do that, the is[[Construct]]ing check will fail us when the bound function is called on instances of the binded function. Hmm.

So, we will need to balance the trade-offs of the possible solutions. The MDN polyfill could be changed in the way you suggest, could be changed to pass `Object.create(fToBind.prototype)` instead of `this`, etc.

```
Property                      | current MDN |  your    | … with same
                              | polyfill    | solution | prototypes
------------------------------+-------------------------------------------
fBound(…) uses boundThis      | yes           yes        yes
                              | 
new fBound(…) ignores it      | yes           yes        yes
                              |
fBound.call(new fToBind)      | yes           yes        no
 uses boundThis               |
                              |
new fToBind instanceof fBound | no            no         yes
                              |
new fBound instanceof fBound  | yes           yes        yes
                              |
new fBound instanceof fToBind | yes           no         yes
                              |
Object.getPrototypeOf(new     | no            no         yes
 fBound)==fToBind.prototype   |
```