# Explanation of a line in MDN bind polyfill

Tags: javascript

The MDN bind polyfill is shown below.

I am trying to work out the purpose of

```
this instanceof fNOP ? this : oThis
```

in the `fToBind.apply` invocation.

I can't get my head around it. Can someone help shed some light?

```
Function.prototype.bindMdn = function(oThis) {
    if (typeof this !== 'function') {
        // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5
        // internal IsCallable function
        throw new TypeError('Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable');
    }
    var aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)
      , fToBind = this
      , fNOP = function() {}
      , fBound = function() {
        return fToBind.apply(this instanceof fNOP ? this : oThis, aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
    }
    ;
    if (this.prototype) {
        // Function.prototype doesn't have a prototype property
        fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;
    }
    fBound.prototype = new fNOP();
    return fBound;
};
```

It seems to be a short-circuit if an instance of the bound function is supplied as the target when invoking the bound function, but the typeof check should catch this, so I don't understand its presence.

Link to the MDN page:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

**Edit:** This is a different question from the suggested duplicate. The suggested duplicate asks why `fNOP` is needed. I fully grok that.

This question is why the `instanceof` check is needed and what function it serves. I present my short-circuit hypothesis above, together with a reason why that doesn't fully make sense.

Comment: Would you mind add link of MDN page please?

Comment: @mortezaT [MDN: Function.prototype.bind() Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Polyfill)

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [MDN Function.prototype.bind bound function called as constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23693282)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MDN Function.prototype.bind bound function called as constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23693282/mdn-function-prototype-bind-bound-function-called-as-constructor)

Comment: It is not a duplicate of that question. This is a fundamentally different question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use the result of a `.bind` to create a new instance with `new`:

```
 function TestClass(a,b,c,d) {
 }

 var TestClassBound = TestClass.bindMdn(null, 1, 2, 3);

 new TestClassBound();
```

Then `this instanceof fNOP` is `true`.

The `typeof this !== 'function'` is just there to test if it was called a regular way on a function and not with `call` or `apply` or to make sure it was not copied to another objects prototype. So it only prevent something like

```
Function.prototype.bind.call("Not a function", 1, 2, 3);
```

Or

```
var testObj = {};
testObj.bind = Function.prototype.bind;

testObj.bind(1,2,3);
```

For every regular call of `bind` on a function the `typeof this` will always be `function`.

So the `typeof this !== 'function'` is to check if the object `bind` is called is really a function.

And the `this instanceof fNOP` within the `fBind` ensures that the behaviour is correct when the result of the binding is used.

Comment: _"And the this instanceof fNOP within the fBind ensures that the behaviour is correct when the result of the binding is used."_ Which behavior ? My understanding is, when you prepend the function call with a `new`, the hard-bound function will be called with a plain new object bound to the hard-bound function's `this`, so `this instanceof fNOP` is the same as `[plain object created because of new] instanceof fNOP`, which means the condition will return false (since `fNOP`'s prototype does not exist in the prototype chain of the newly created object), which means `this` will be set incorrectly

Comment: So `this` will be bound to `oThis`, which shouldn't be the case if the `new` operator is used, if the `new` operator is used, `this` should be bound to the new object created by the `new` operator behind-the-scenes.

Comment: Moreover, what does `fNOP` stand for ? I assume the "f" is there for "function", what about the other three letters ?

Comment: @Taurus `nop` is a common abbreviation for `no operation` and it is used when something is needed, even if it doesn't do anything itself.

Comment: @Taurus I'm not sure what you want to say with the other comment. Do you think the implementation of MDN is wrong?