# How is `new` operator able to override hard-binding, in the Function.prototype.bind(..)

Tags: javascript, new-operator

This is a purely theoretical question.
I am learing javascript from 'you don't know js', and i was stuck on the implementation of the `bind` function in JS. consider the following code:

```js
function foo(something) {
  this.a = something;
}

var obj1 = {};

var bar = foo.bind(obj1);
bar(2);
console.log(obj1.a); // 2

var baz = new bar(3);
console.log(obj1.a); // 2
console.log(baz.a); // 3
```

In the above snippet, we bind `foo()` to `obj1`, so the `this` in `foo()` belongs to `obj1` and that's why `obj1.a` becomes `2` when we call `bar(2)`. but the `new` operator is able to take precedence and `obj1.a` does not change even when `bar(3)` is called with `new`.

Below is the polyfill provided by the MDN page for `bind(..)`:

```
if (!Function.prototype.bind) {
Function.prototype.bind = function(oThis) {
    if (typeof this !== "function") {
        // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5
        // internal IsCallable function
        throw new TypeError( "Function.prototype.bind - what " +
            "is trying to be bound is not callable"
        );
    }

    var aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ),
        fToBind = this,
        fNOP = function(){},
        fBound = function(){
            return fToBind.apply(
                (
                    this instanceof fNOP &&
                    oThis ? this : oThis
                ),
                aArgs.concat( Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments ) )
            );
        }
    ;

    fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;
    fBound.prototype = new fNOP();

    return fBound;
};
}
```

The part that's allowing new overriding according to the book, is:

```
this instanceof fNOP &&
oThis ? this : oThis

// ... and:

fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;
fBound.prototype = new fNOP();
```

so , now the main point. according to the book: 
"We won't actually dive into explaining how this trickery works (it's complicated and beyond our scope here), but essentially the utility determines whether or not the hard-bound function has been called with new (resulting in a newly constructed object being its this), and if so, it uses that newly created this rather than the previously specified hard binding for this."

how is the logic in the `bind()` function allows `new` operator to override the hard binding?

Comment: You may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367768/how-to-detect-if-a-function-is-called-as-constructor) useful.

Comment: Languages have compile-time and runtime semantics that are defined and implemented. When a JS program is parsed and compiled, calls with the `new` operator are found. This operator is known to be used to call a function with the intent of constructing a new object. As such, the specific algorithm(s) defined by the spec for this circumstance are followed. Part of that, like any call, is setting `this` to the proper value. There's no real magic. The language implementation is just following rules.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that polyfills are "best effort" implementations written purely in JS. They have no access to the language implementation's internals, and so are sometimes unable to perfectly represent the requirements of the spec.

Comment: Here is a simple example `function Foo(x) { console.log(this instanceof Foo); }`   ->  `Foo(4)` = false  `new Foo(4)` = true.

Comment: @Utkanos that was really helpful but still didn't explain how is `new` able to take precedence over hard binding

Comment: Are you asking how native `bind` is specified to work in the ECMAScript spec, or how and why the behavior of `this instanceof fNOP && oThis` polyfill works?

Comment: yes mainly how the logic of the polyfil allowing `new` to take precedence

Comment: If you're just asking how the polyfill works, you need to clarify that, because your question looks more like you're asking about the relationship of the `new` operator to functions with a bound `this` value.

Comment: i have edited the last  part to make it more clear

Comment: That really didn't make it any more clear. Your question is still asking how *the `new` operator* is able to override hard-binding, but then you now seem to be saying that you want to know how a specific `.bind()` polyfill method is able to *replicate* the native behavior of `new`.

Comment: "essentially the utility determines whether or not the hard-bound function has been called with new (resulting in a newly constructed object being its this), and if so, it uses that newly created this rather than the previously specified hard binding for this."  and so the new operator able to override hard binding, due to the logic in polyfill. i have mentioned clearly how is the logic in the polyfill determining that weather the function is called with new, if so then new will take precedence. how is the logic in the code working so that new will override hard binding?

Comment: See, again you're asking about how `new`, which is an operator, does an override, but then you say it's about the polyfill, which doesn't determine how `new` works, but rather includes logic to emulate how the bound function should behave when invoked with new. That's why your question is unclear. On top of that, you talk about how JavaScript's `.bind()` is implemented but you don't make it clear when you're talking about the native implementation and when you're talking about the polyfill.

Comment: That said, I've answered both questions below.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MDN Function.prototype.bind bound function called as constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23693282/1048572)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, it is important to understand the difference between an object's prototype (represented the spec as `[[Prototype]]` and accessible via the function `Object.getPrototypeOf` or the deprecated `__proto__` property) and the property on a function whose name is `prototype`. Every function has a property named `prototype` which is used when the function is called with `new`.

When you call a function with `new`, that function is supplied with a `this` value set to a newly-constructed object whose prototype (i.e., `[[Prototype]]`) is set to the `prototype` property of the function being called. That is, when you call `new Foo()`, then when the code inside `Foo` is run, the `this` value will be an object of the form

```
{ [[Prototype]]: Foo.prototype }
```

Let's briefly meet the cast of variables:

- `fToBind` is the function being bound: for `foo.bind(...)`, `foo` is `fToBind`.
- `fBound` is the bound version of `fToBind`; it is the returned value of the `bind` operation. `fBound` acts like a gatekeeper for the original `fToBind` function, and decides what `this` value `fToBind` gets when it is invoked.
- `oThis` is the first argument supplied to `bind`, i.e., the object being bound to the function's `this`.
- `fNOP` is a function whose `prototype` property is set to `fToBind.prototype`
- `fBound.prototype = new fNOP()` causes these to be true:

  ```
  Object.getPrototypeOf(fBound.prototype) === fNOP.prototype
  Object.getPrototypeOf(fBound.prototype) === fToBind.prototype
  ```

When `fBound` is called with `new`, then the `this` that is supplied to `fBound` is of the form

```
{ [[Prototype]]: fBound.prototype }
```

and `fBound.prototype` is an object of the form

```
{ [[Prototype]]: fNOP.prototype }
```

making the full form of `this` equivalent to

```
{ [[Prototype]]: { [[Prototype]]: fNOP.prototype } }
```

So, `fNOP.prototype` is in the prototype chain of the newly-created `this` object when `fBound` is called with `new`. That's exactly what the `object instanceof constructor` operation tests for:

> The `instanceof` operator tests the presence of `constructor.prototype` in `object`'s prototype chain.

The order of operations between `&&` and ternary here is:

```
(this instanceof fNOP && oThis) ? this : oThis
```

If `this` has `fNOP.prototype` in its prototype chain *and* the original `bind` call was given a truthy first argument to bind to the function, then use the natrually-created `this` supplied to `fBound` when it is called with `new` and supply that to `fToBind` instead of the bound `this`.

Comment: This: `fBound.prototype.__proto__ === fNOP.prototype` and this: 
`fBound.prototype.__proto__ === fToBind.prototype` can't both be true. Maybe for the second one you meant `fNOP.prototype === fToBind.prototype`?

Comment: "*represented in code as `__proto__`*" - please don't use that anymore, anywhere - it's deprecated and needs to die! Use `Object.create`/`Object.getPrototypeOf`/`Object.setPrototypeOf` instead.

Comment: @Bergi I don't disagree! Would you rather I express an object's prototype using `[[Prototype]]` internal slot notation in this answer? Or are you simply cautioning against using it in actual code (a position I wholeheartedly endorse)?

Comment: @apsillers Both, I think.

Comment: @Bergi extermination complete `:)`

Comment: so as i understand the object's prototype is still represented in the code as `__proto__`, and in the spec as `[[Prototype]]`. it is important to note this, because almost all the tutorials on internet use both these terms which confuses the beginners, and this answer has cleared a lot of things at the same time

Answer (score 2):

`new` takes precedence over a bound `this` value because that's how the language was defined.

First you have a function. Then you bind a `this` value, and call it normally. As expected, the value of `this` is the bound value.

Then you call that same function with `new`, and your value is overridden. Why? Because calls using `new` are instructed by the language design, and therefore by the language implementation, to ignore the bound `this` value, and replace it with the new object being constructed.

A language implementation is just a program. And like any other program, it follows rules. So the rule in this case is that `new` gets to dictate the value of `this` irrespective of any bound value.

Comment: I can see you have posted two answers (is that possible?) you can merge the other answer with this

Comment: Yes you can have multiple anwsers, and I'm effectively answering two very different questions, depending on how the post is interpreted, so I prefer to keep them separate.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're just asking about how they got the polyfill to work.

In that polyfill, `fNOP` is a no-op function (does nothing when called) that is used simply to have its `.prototype` inserted into the prototype chain of the returned `fBound` function. That's done here:

```
fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;
fBound.prototype = new fNOP();
```

So then when the `fBound` function (the one that gets returned to the caller of `.bind()`) is invoked, the `instanceof` operator can check the `this` value inside the `fBound` function to see if that value is an instance of `fNOP`. And if it is, it infers that `new` was used.

This works (sort of) because `instanceof` will start at the object it's given on its left hand side, and search the prototype chain to see if any of them are the same object as the `.prototype` object of the function on its right side. So if `new` was invoked, the `this` value will be a new object that has `fNOP.prototype` in its prototype chain because of the setup that was performed as shown above.

*However*, this isn't a perfect means of testing. For example, the `.call()` method could have been used to set the `this` value of the call to some other instance of the `fBound` function. So it will look like `new` was used even when it wasn't, and as such, the bound value for `this` will not be used as the `this` value of the call to the original function.