# Can I spawn a Web Worker and inject JavaScript (created at runtime by parent) into it from the parent "process"?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

Is it possible to spawn a web worker, and somehow inject parent-generated JavaScript into it from the parent thread? ie. without having to make the worker include a file, rather I want the parent to inject it somehow.

An example could be where the parent creates a bunch of math functions at run time, then creates a Web worker to run them.

Comment: You could transmit the code using the usual `send()` and then use `new Function()` in the worker to convert it into a function.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to send the functions code through the usual channel and use the constructor [`new Function()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) (or [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)) to recreate the function.

In both cases you should check, what is actually transmitted to prevent security risks.

**main script**

```
// your function given as arguments and code
var funktion = {
  args: ['a', 'b' ],
  source: 'return a + b;'
};

// send it to your worker
worker.postMessage( funktion );
```

**worker**

```
self.addEventListener( 'message', function( msg ){

  // build array for constructor arguments
  var args = [ null ].concat( fk.a, fk.c );

  // create function
  var yourFunc = new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(Function, args));

  // use yourFunc
});
```

This uses the dynamic use of the `Function` constructor as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8843181/1169798).

---

Using `eval()` may be simpler depending on how you have the function's code:

**main script**

```
// your function given as arguments and code
var funktion = "function add(a,b){ return a + b; }";

// send it to your worker
worker.postMessage( funktion );
```

**worker**

```
self.addEventListener( 'message', function( msg ){      

  // create function
  var yourFunc = eval( "(function(){ return " + funktion + "; })()" );

  // use yourFunc
});
```

Comment: I think it is possible to use a module bundler to bundle modules somehow and send the whole thing to a general web worker through postMessage, which then evals it. It is just a security risk, but you can sign the whole thing and the worker could check the digital signature before evaling. Maybe that gives a little safety, idk. (Still it would not make much sense, because you could use the bundle.js by creating the worker.)

Comment: @inf3rno the bundler changes nothing in the overall concept, I think. your still sending some string with code and evaluating it on the other end. As for security, it highly depends on where the source code is generated. If this is purely within the same browser, I do not really see an security issue, as all you can do is "hack" yourself.

Comment: Yes the concept is the same, but with a bundler you can use normal js code instead of writing it as string. Normally you have dependencies and you can send all of them along with the code, not just a single function on closure without external dependencies. Signing it gives a little extra security, because your worker cannot be injected by ppl using XSS.

Answer (score 1):

This question is almost 10yrs old so things have changed since it was asked. It was also asked without context on what it means to "inject functions". Do you want to inject single functions into an existing environment or do you want to run whole scripts or do you want to inject functions into scripts.

In any case, you can run a script via in a worker via a blob

```js
const script = `
function doIt() {
  console.log('hello world');
}
doIt();
`;
const blob = new Blob([script], {type: 'application/javascript'});
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
const worker = new Worker(url);
```

If you run the script above and check the JavaScript console you'll see it ran

Another solution is to run a [service worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API). A service worker effectively intercepts network requests from the page and lets you apply JavaScript to them before they are sent to the network itself.

So, effectively you can return your own strings from the service-worker in response to requests from the webpage or workers. You can put functions in those strings and you can provide the strings by sending them to the service-worker

In pseudo-code

```
// service-worker.js
let injectString = '';

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {

  event.respondWith(async function() {
    const url = new URL(event.request.url);
    if (url.pathname === 'inject-fn.js')
      const response = new Response(injectString, {
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/javascript'},
      });
      return response;
    }
    return await fetch(event.request);
  }());
}

self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  injectString = event.data;
});
```

This makes it so if the worker requests `'inject-fn.js'` then it will receive the string stored in `injectString`, otherwise it will go the network as normal

To set the string you post a message to the service-worker and the load the script

```js
  const worker = navigator.serviceWorker?.controller || navigator.serviceWorker?.active;

  worker.postMessage(`
    function doIt() {
      console.log('hello world');
    }
  `);
  
  new Worker('inject-fn.js');
```

you might need to append a query or something to make sure the browser doesn't load 'inject-fn.js' from the cache. As in

```
  new Worker(`inject-fn.js?${Math.random()});
```

The advantage to using a service-worker is from the POV of the page, the scripts come from the same URL where as via a blob they do not and so can not reference resources without absolute paths. Another problem with blobs is they are hard to debug because every time they're run them they'll get a random blob URL so any break points you set on the code in the blob will not match the next time.

The disadvantage to using a service-worker is they are finicky, at least in my experience.

Note: the code above is pseudo-code. It takes more code to properly start a service-worker and communicate with it. [This site](https://jsgist.org), for which the code is on github, and which is effectively a static web page, uses both techniques. The service worker when it can. The blob when it can not.

Comment: "the scripts come from the same domain where as via a blob they do not and so can not reference resources without absolute paths and those resources will be considered from another domain" This is not entirely true. They are same-domain. `self.origin` will match the parent page's origin. For instance you can `fetch(yourResource)` just fine. The issue is that the base-URL is different. So it really just concerns the resolution of relative URLs that are affected.

Comment: Yip, JS generated at runtime by the parent, thanks. Question now edited.

Comment: @kaiido, The path issue is enough to make them "not the same domain".

Comment: No it's not enough. The domain is preserved, since it's part of the host which is used to generate the origin. Maybe you were talking about the base?

Comment: You're using a pendantic defintion of "same domain". I'm using "this script runs unmodified" definition. If I have to change the paths, it's not the same domain. The file is not served from the same domain, it may have permissions like it's on the same domain but it can not load things from relative paths nor root paths like something actually on the same domain. Every path has to be fully qualified, unlike paths on the same domain.

Comment: No, it's not pedantic, we're on a technical programming site. There is no definition of "same-domain". There is a `document.domain`, which doesn't concern Workers directly, but FWIW, note that it is maintained for Documents served from blob: URLs. And then there is the "domain" part of an URL's pathname, which is preserved in the case of a Worker, even the sub-domain part is. What's colloquially called "same-domain" here and there, is actually `same-origin`. And the Worker served through a blob: URL is `same-origin` with the URL creator.

Comment: By your definition of "same-domain" the same HTML page stops being same-domain with itself if it contains a `<base href="">`. I guess you can see how this definition isn't really useful.