# create new objects using arrays providing parameters

Tags: javascript

I have no idea how to even look for an answer to this question. I've tried loads of variations of search to no avail.

I bet it's the most simple thing too.

I need to use an array to store parameters for a `new` object.

```
var params = [0, 0, false];
var obj = new google.maps.LatLng(params);
```

Obviously the above will fail as it doesn't accept an array, but separate parameters. This is just an example.

I'd rather not have to step through the array, like `params[0]`.

The reason is, I am wanting to set up an object factory, that may have variable parameter lists, so I would set some options, with a `type`, and array of `params`, and then when I call a `create` function it does

```
var factory = new Factory({
  type: 'LatLng',
  params: [0, 0, false]
});

var latLng = factory.create();
```

Comment: `google.maps.LatLng.apply(this, params);`

Comment: @tymeJV: Yeah, but can you do that with `new`?

Comment: Use of .apply() with 'new' operator. Is this possible? http://stackoverflow.com/q/1606797/985454

Comment: @RocketHazmat -- Ah...I have no idea! (And from your comment below, apparently not :\ )

Comment: @Qwerty: Thanks for finding that!! :-D