# How does Function.prototype.bind.apply work?

Tags: javascript

I saw this question in stackoverflow and seriously did not understand on how does `Function.prototype.bind.apply` work?

[Use of .apply() with 'new' operator. Is this possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606797/use-of-apply-with-new-operator-is-this-possible/8843181#8843181)

```
function Shan(name){
   this.name = name;
}

var s = new (Function.prototype.bind.call(Shan, "shankar"));
```

The above code returns me an instance of `Shan constructor`.

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2015-06-18/code-snippets-and-in-the-darkness-bind-them/

Comment: What exactly is the question?  Is your code working and you want to know why it works?  Or is your code not working and you want to know why it doesn't work?  In general, you don't use `.apply()` with constructors, but rather create a factory function that can do the work for you.

Comment: @jfriend00: Wanted to understand on how Function.prototype.bind.call works?

Comment: Does the code you posted work?

Comment: Are you asking about call or apply? Your question contradicts your code