# Leaking arguments when using Function.apply

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, arguments, bind, apply

I was reading on GitHub in **petkaantonov/bluebird on [Optimization killers](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#optimization-killers)**. And when reaching chapter **[3.3 what-is-safe-arguments-usage](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#what-is-safe-arguments-usage)** specifically the part [What is safe arguments usage?](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#what-is-safe-arguments-usage) I realized that I might be going wrong using `bind` and `apply` in my project.

The post states:

> Be aware that adding properties to functions (e.g. `fn.$inject =...`) and bound functions (i.e. the result of `Function#bind`) generate hidden classes and, therefore, are **not safe** when using `#apply`.

I used [this answer on the question **Use of .apply() with 'new' operator. Is this possible?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8843181/1697459) to be able to pass an array of arguments to my constructor function like this:

```
new (Cls.bind.apply(Cls, arguments))();
```

This looks suspiciously much like what is described as **not safe** in the post.
Is this true? Am I going wrong here?

I would simply like to understand if the issue in the post applies to this example case, especially because it might be useful to comment on the answer so others don't make the same error *(the post is heavily upvoted so it seems people are using this solution a lot)*.

**Note:** I recently found out about [the spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) (awesome) which is a nice alternative, to my previous solution:

```
new Cls(...arguments);
```

Comment: it also says it's ok to pass `arguments` to `apply()`