# Argument gets lost when using bind apply with array arguments

Tags: javascript, arrays, arguments, bind, apply

I used [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8843181/1697459) to construct a new class instance by passing array arguments using the following code:

```
new ( Cls.bind.apply( Cls, arguments ) )();
```

But one of my arguments is an array and the values get lost during construction

You can check an example that demonstrates this [in this CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GqNKoq)

In the example I pass the third argument `properties`:

```
var properties = [
    { name: "first", value: "1" },
    { name: "second", value: "2" },
    { name: "third", value: "3" }
];
```

But the properties in the result is `undefined`.

Apparently something goes wrong here, but what and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is almost correct but you need to pass an additional argument to your `factory()` :
`factory(undefined, name, description, properties)`

This is highlighted in the SO answer you link to in your question:

> The anything parameter doesn't matter much, since the new keyword resets f's context. However, it is required for syntactical reasons. Now, for the bind call: We need to pass a variable number of arguments, so this does the trick:
>   var f = Cls.bind.apply(Cls, [anything, arg1, arg2, ...]);
>   result = new f();