# Alternative solution to eval() when creating object dynamically in a closure?

Tags: javascript

At the moment I am using `eval()` to create an object dynamically, function constructor called is actually in closure.

The string in `eval()`, in my real app code is created based on a condition.

I would like to know if it is possible to achieve the same result avoid using `eval()`.

I would be interested in a solution which avoiding adding `Icon` and `Logo` to `window`global, and using syntax like `window[myDesiredFunction]` when declaring the new object. Also I cannot use any hard-coded switch case statements.

```js
(function(window){
    var Icon = function(id){
       this.id = id;
    };
    var Logo = function(id){
       this.id = id;
    };
    var app = {
        start:function(){
            var item1 = eval("new Icon('iconA')");  // i need replace eval()
            var item2 = eval("new Logo('logoB')");  // just as example string will be created with some condition dynamically
            console.log(item1 .id);
            console.log(item2 .id);
        }
    };
    app.start();
})(window);
```

Comment: Can you please give some data which you want to convert in eval

Comment: well create an object wich will store these two constructors (then call it like `new myConstructors['Icon']('iconA')`)

Comment: `var constructors = { Icon : Icon, Logo : Logo }; var item1 = new constructors["Icon"]("iconA");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store your constructors in an object, and if you want to use a variable number of arguments you need use the technique described here [Use of .apply() with 'new' operator. Is this possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606797/use-of-apply-with-new-operator-is-this-possible).

The resulting code will look like this:

```
(function(window) {
  function Icon(id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  function Logo(id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  var constructors = {
    Icon: Icon,
    Logo: Logo
  }


  function createObject(name, arguments) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    args.unshift(null);
    return new(Function.prototype.bind.apply(constructors[name], args));
  }

  var app = {
    start: function() {
      var item1 = createObject('Icon', ['iconA']);
      var item2 = createObject('Logo', ['logoB']);
      console.dir(item1);
      console.dir(item2);
    }
  };
  app.start();
})(window);
```