# How does function.prototype.apply work when thisArg is part of the same array as subsequent args

Tags: javascript, prototype, apply

As the data for a date/temperature scatter-plot, I wanted to be able to key the data with a date-like string, and the following is the structure I devised:

```
  var dateTemperatures = {
      '[2016,8,29]': {low: 63, high: 94},
      '[2016,9,2]': {low: 59, high: 81},
      '[2016,9,1]': {low: 58, high: 85}
  }
```

The idea being that I could call JSON.parse on the keys, and have the arguments necessary to create a date.  Then I found [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8843181/34806) as to how to create an object, using a combination of both `apply` and `new .... ()`, and in particular used the following substituting `Something` with `Date`:

```
var s = new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(Something, [null, a, b, c]));
```

And it works like a charm, for instance in the following function I devised for ordering the "Date" keys:

```
  function orderTemperatureDates(dateTemperatures) {
      var orderedDates = [];

      for (var temperatureDate in dateTemperatures) {
          var YMD = JSON.parse(temperatureDate);
          YMD.unshift(null); //standard first argument to .apply()
          orderedDates.push(new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(Date, YMD)));
      }

      return orderedDates.sort(function(a,b){return a.getTime() - b.getTime()});
  }
```

CONSOLE/LOG/OUTPUT:

```
[Thu Sep 29 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time), Sat Oct 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time), Sun Oct 02 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)]
```

Going back to the example line from the referenced Stackoverflow answer though, how does this work?  Because my understanding, per [documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), is that `null` can be the first argument to `apply` followed by the remaining arguments, but in the example and in my code, null and all of the remaining arguments are part of one and the same array.

Comment: BTW I've released a gist for the entire scatter-plot at https://gist.github.com/dexygen/40f333657afc17aabbbcf5597bd3871e

Comment: "in the example and in my code, null and all of the remaining arguments are part of one and the same array" You're still feeding 2 parameters to `apply` though...

Comment: @AndréDion The first parameter being passed to apply is the function/constructor to invoke.  Somewhere somehow to me at least it seems that `null` needs to get shifted off the front of the array to which it belongs (the second argument to apply) in order for the code to work, so it seems a little "magical" to me right now.  I think it may have something to do with how bind works but cannot figure out exactly how: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: [The first argument to `apply` is `thisArg`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). The second argument (`argsArray`) are arguments to be passed into the function you're `apply`ing.

Comment: @AndréDion I could be wrong but in this case I think the first argument is the thisArg to `bind`, *not* `apply`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My understanding is that `null` can be the first argument to `apply` followed by the remaining argument

Yes, you *can* pass `null` as the first argument of `apply` *when* you want the `this` value inside the method to be `null` (or generally don't care about it). But that is not the case here.

In `new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(Date, [null, 2016, 8, 29]))` we don't pass `null` as the first argument to `apply`, because we don't want that. We are applying the `bind` method, and we need to apply it to `Date`, with the rest of the arguments. The call is equivalent to

```
new (Date.bind(null, 2016, 8, 29))
```

where we are passing `null` as the first argument to [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), because we don't care about the value that will get ignored anyway when the bound function is invoked with the `new` keyword.

Have a look at this example:

```js
function constructor(a, b, c) {
  "use strict";
  console.log(this, a, b, c);
}
var bound = constructor.bind(null, 1, 2, 3);
bound();
new bound();
```

---

If you know that `YMD` always has three elements, it would be easier to write `new Date(YMD[0], YMD[1], YMD[2])`. If you were using ES6, you could also use spread syntax `new Date(...YMD)` for the call.

Comment: Boy I had blinders on and was convinced I needed to use `apply`.  Thanks for your explanation and the suggested alternative approach.

Comment: Yeah, you need to use `apply` only if you don't know how many arguments to pass. Otherwise `call` or just direct invocation are enough.

Comment: Also, whenever you use `bind`, you are creating new functions. Creating functions in a loop is bad for performance. You can use apply, bind or call more creatively to create a general constructor if you care for performance.

Comment: @GökhanKurt Actually, using `bind` is the only (non-eval, pre-ES6) way to pass arbitrarily many arguments into a native constructor.

Comment: @Bergi You can write your own constructor to extend the native one' prototype, and use `apply` on the native constructor, I think. I always do that to implement OOP and inheritance in javascript. In case of `Date` though, `Date` doesn't let you use its prototype methods on objects of other type. I don't know why was it implemented like that.

Comment: @GökhanKurt No, the whole point is that you *cannot* use `apply` with native constructors - it only calls them like a function (without `new`), and no instance will be initialised. Only ES6 `super` really fixes that.

Comment: @Bergi I didn't know that. Thank you.