# Can I create a Date object from a predefined string (typescript)?

Tags: date, typescript

I have a value returned in a string (numbers separated by commas) and I'd like to make a Date object out of it. It looks like this is not possible, can someone confirm and/or suggest me a solution.
This does not work :

```
let dateString='2017,3,22,0';
let dateFromString = new Date(dateString);
```

This works though (when I pass a list of numbers) :

```
let dateFromString = new Date(2017,3,22,0);
```

And this works also :

```
let dateString = '2008/05/10 12:08:20';
let dateFromString = new Date(dateString);
```

The goal would be to create a Date object from a uniform string. Is that possible ?

Can I create a Date object from a predefined string, which has only one type of separator (comma, colon, slash or whatever) ?

Comment: what is your actual problem?

Comment: updated question. can i create a date object from a predefined string which uses only one character as separator ?

Comment: And what exactly uniform string do you want to use - `2017,3,22,0` or `2008/05/10 12:08:20`?

Comment: I want to avoid using `,` and `:` both as separator. I would like to use only one certain character as separator, either `,`, `:` or `/` or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your environment is compatible with ES6 (eg. Babel, TypeScript, modern Chrome/Firefox etc), you can use the string's `.split(',')` and decompose the array into arguments like the following:

```js
const dateString = '2017,3,22,0';
const date = new Date(...dateString.split(','));  // date object for 2017/03/22
```

ES5 compatible version:

```js
var dateString = '2017,1,2,0';
var date = new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(Date, [null].concat(dateString.split(','))));
```

As for how the `.bind.apply` method works with `new`, you can take a look at [Use of .apply() with 'new' operator. Is this possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606797/use-of-apply-with-new-operator-is-this-possible)

**Note:** Thanks to the two comments below for spotting my errors

Comment: `const` is not compatible with ES5

Comment: It should be `new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(Date, [null].concat(dateString.split(','))))`

Comment: Thanks hindmost and abhishekkannojia 

Comment: I am actually using Typescript + Angular2 and the compiler will compile to ES5...unfortunatelly both of the suggested options are failing. I know I could parse the string and pass to Date what it needs, I was just wondering if there is a simple solution like using `split()`.

Comment: How is it failing? The TypeScript compilation, or type checking? It appears to compile fine on http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/

Comment: +1, the answer is correct, it is failing only in my dev environment. I'm getting `error TS2345: Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'null[] | null'.`, i guess i have to figure it out

Comment: Maybe using `.split(',').map(i => +i)` to force the resulting array type to be `number[]` rather than `string[]` could work?